# What is DNS setting in *.network systemd-netword for when without /etc/resolve.conf does not work?

Tags: linux, dns, systemd

This is content of the `/etc/systemd/network/dhcp.network` file for `systemd-networkd` in Arch Linux.

```
[Match]
Name=en*

[Network]
DHCP=v4
DNS=8.8.8.8
```

I expected that this would be everything necessary to get the Internet working but DNS did not work without adding `8.8.8.8` to `/etc/resolv.conf`. What is the purpose of the DNS setting in *.network file then?

Answer (score 0):

If you run a name server on your local host, you have to set it up separately. If your are on a local network and have the opportunity to use an existing nameserver, this should always be preferred. If no nameserver option is given, the resolver attempts to connect to the name server on the local host and this most important option in resolv.conf is nameserver, which gives the IP-address of a name server to use.